# How can I increase system_ext partition in AOSP?

Tags: android-source

I was trying to add a .so file into /system/lib with PRODUCT_COPY_FILES, but once I try to build it it fails with this error:

```
ExternalError: Failed to run command '['lpmake', '--metadata-size', '65536', '--super-name', 'system', '--metadata-slots', '2', '--auto-slot-suffixing', '--device', 'system:2952790016', '--device', 'vendor:805306368', '--device'
, 'product:314572800', '--group', 'google_dynamic_partitions:4069523456', '--partition', 'system:readonly:2344202240:google_dynamic_partitions', '--image', 'system=/home/markus/EPhone/ethOS/out/target/product/blueline/obj/PACKAG
ING/target_files_intermediates/lineage_blueline-target_files-eng.markus/IMAGES/system.img', '--partition', 'vendor:readonly:452227072:google_dynamic_partitions', '--image', 'vendor=/home/markus/EPhone/ethOS/out/target/product/bl
ueline/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/lineage_blueline-target_files-eng.markus/IMAGES/vendor.img', '--partition', 'product:readonly:1016426496:google_dynamic_partitions', '--image', 'product=/home/markus/EPhone/ethOS/o
ut/target/product/blueline/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/lineage_blueline-target_files-eng.markus/IMAGES/product.img', '--partition', 'system_ext:readonly:266698752:google_dynamic_partitions', '--image', 'system_ext=/
home/markus/EPhone/ethOS/out/target/product/blueline/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/lineage_blueline-target_files-eng.markus/IMAGES/system_ext.img', '--sparse', '--output', '/home/markus/EPhone/ethOS/out/target/product
/blueline/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/lineage_blueline-target_files-eng.markus/OTA']' (exit code 70):
lpmake I 12-25 19:38:11 10456 10456 builder.cpp:1031] [liblp]Partition system will resize from 0 bytes to 2344202240 bytes
lpmake I 12-25 19:38:11 10456 10456 builder.cpp:1031] [liblp]Partition vendor will resize from 0 bytes to 452227072 bytes
lpmake I 12-25 19:38:11 10456 10456 builder.cpp:1031] [liblp]Partition product will resize from 0 bytes to 1016426496 bytes
lpmake E 12-25 19:38:11 10456 10456 builder.cpp:620] [liblp]Partition system_ext is part of group google_dynamic_partitions which does not have enough space free (266698752 requested, 3812855808 used out of 4069523456)
Not enough space on device for partition system_ext with size 266698752
```

How can I increase the space on system_ext, so I can include the .so file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change BoardConfig file, similar to https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_google_crosshatch/commit/155109c657c804ca14e4cbb78ddc2caf5bfeda46 but for `BOARD_SYSTEM_EXTIMAGE_PARTITION_RESERVED_SIZE` (just in case if you need to change `BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_RESERVED_SIZE` later).

FYI `blueline` is built on `crossnatch` product tree.